# Indices font size & color

Tags: interface

Does anyone know how to increase the  indices (e.g. for vertex ids) font size and/or color in the viewport. Currently its a '2 pixel navy colored font on a dark grey backdrop' which can only be read by nocturnal species.

I'm using blender 2.93

[image: sample]

Comment: I wonder why they chose this color and size. It's really hard to see. Ridiculous lol. Good question!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change it in your preferences->themes->3D Viewport

[image]

color: Face Angle text

point size: vertex size

font size: you can change it here:

[image]

but....it will change more than you want...i guess ;)

Comment: Perfect! Solved! Thank you so much

Comment: you are welcome